# Updating customtkinter.frame()

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

For my app, I'm designing a frame switching system, but I don't know how to update the screen for when the user changes logins.

```
def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()
```

```
class LoginScreen(customtkinter.CTkFrame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        customtkinter.CTkFrame.__init__(self, parent, width=width, height=height)
        self.controller = controller
        self.location_x = 0.5
        label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self, text="Login")
        label.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.4, anchor=customtkinter.CENTER)
        username = customtkinter.CTkEntry(self, placeholder_text="Name")
        username.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=customtkinter.CENTER)
        button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, text="Back",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        button.place(relx=0.45, rely=0.6, anchor=customtkinter.CENTER)
        confirm = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, text="Confirm",
                            command=lambda: self.check_login(str(username.get())))
        confirm.place(relx=0.55, rely=0.6, anchor=customtkinter.CENTER)

    def check_login(self, username):
        if hashlib.sha256(bytes(username, encoding='ascii')).hexdigest() in people.people.keys():
            self.controller.API_KEY = people.people[hashlib.sha256(bytes(username, encoding='ascii')).hexdigest()]
            self.controller.show_frame('Dashboard')
            self.controller.show_frame('Sidebar')
```

```
class Sidebar(customtkinter.CTkFrame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        customtkinter.CTkFrame.__init__(self, parent, fg_color="black", bg_color="red", width=300, border_color="orange", border_width=10, height=height)

        for index, course in enumerate(api.pull_courses(controller.API_KEY)):
            course_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, text=course,
                            command=lambda index=index: controller.show_frame('ClassPage' + str(index)))
            course_button.place(relx=0.5, rely=((index + 1) * ((0.6)/9))+0.2, anchor=customtkinter.CENTER)
```

How would I update `Dashboard` and `Sidebar` before showing the frame? They need to update the course name when I change the API_KEY. Basically if I log in with my login, it would show my courses, but if I login with a different login (Which doesn't need to update because the login screen stays the same), I should see my friend's courses.

Comment: you can first create instance of `Sidebar` and later send it to `LoginScreen` as parameter - and `LoginScreen` will have have direct access to `Sidebar`

Comment: other method: you can get code from function `self.controller.show_frame('Sidebar')` and create new function `sidebar = self.controller.get_frame('Sidebar')` which will give access to other frame - and this way one frame may get access to another frame (without showing it) and it may change its content.

Comment: frankly, `Sidebar` shouldn't have all code in `__init__()` but in in seperated function i.e `set_data()` and run it in `__init__()` - and this way `LoginScreen` can also run `set_data()` to change content in `Sidebar`

Comment: another method: every frame should have function `on_show()` which is always executed  in `self.controller.show_frame()` for new frame (which you will show), and second function `on_hide()` which is always executed in `self.controller.show_frame()` for old frame (which you hide) - and `Sidebar` may use `on_show()` to check if there is new login and update content before you show it. I think this method was in some very old question on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Sidebar` don't create buttons directly in `__init__` but in separted function - ie. `set_data()`

```
class Sidebar(customtkinter.CTkFrame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        customtkinter.CTkFrame.__init__(self, parent, fg_color="black", bg_color="red", width=300, border_color="orange", border_width=10, height=height)

        self.controller = controller
       
        self.set_data()  # set at first time
        
    def set_data(self):   
    
        # remove previous buttons (and all other widgets) in this Frame
        for child in self.winfo_children():
            child.destroy()
    
        # create new buttons
        for index, course in enumerate(api.pull_courses(self.controller.API_KEY)):
            course_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, text=course,
                            command=lambda index=index: self.controller.show_frame('ClassPage' + str(index)))
            course_button.place(relx=0.5, rely=((index + 1) * ((0.6)/9))+0.2, anchor=customtkinter.CENTER)
```

And this way later you can run `set_data()` in `LoginScreen` before you show `Sidebar`

```
class LoginScreen(customtkinter.CTkFrame):


    def check_login(self, username):
 
        # ...

        sidebar = self.controller.frames['Sidebar']
        sidebar.set_data()

        self.controller.show_frame('Sidebar')
```

And the same you can do for `Dashboard`.

---

I didn't check if `CTkFrame` can use `self.winfo_children()` to get all buttons in `Frame`.

Comment: I haven't tested it yet, but is it a standard/good practice to make buttons and such in a separate `set_data()` function rather than in the `__init__()` function?

Comment: it is common practice. If you would create all in `__init__()` then you still would need `set_data()` to replace it - and you would have the same code in two places. So don't repeat code but use `set_data()` in `__init__`. Rule `DRY` - `Don't Repeat Yourself`

Comment: Alright thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One of the way is to override `tkraise()` inside `Sidebar` class and create those buttons inside the override function before raising it

```py
class Sidebar(customtkinter.CTkFrame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        super().__init__(parent, fg_color="black", bg_color="red",
                         width=300, border_color="orange", border_width=10,
                         height=height)
        self.controller = controller

    # override tkraise()
    def tkraise(self):
        # clear current buttons
        for w in self.winfo_children():
            w.destroy()

        # create required buttons
        for index, course in enumerate(api.pull_courses(self.controller.API_KEY)):
            course_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, text=course,
                            command=lambda index=index: self.controller.show_frame('ClassPage' + str(index)))
            course_button.place(
                relx=0.5,
                rely=((index + 1) * ((0.6)/9))+0.2, anchor=customtkinter.CENTER
            )

        # raise the frame
        super().tkraise()
```